# Fastest way to find Strings in String collection that begin with certain chars

Tags: java, collections, partial, string-matching

I have a large collection of Strings. I want to be able to find the Strings that begin with "Foo" or the Strings that end with "Bar". What would be the best Collection type to get the fastest results? (I am using Java)

I know that a HashSet is very fast for complete matches, but not for partial matches I would think? So, what could I use instead of just looping through a List? Should I look into LinkedList's or similar types? Are there any Collection Types that are optimized for this kind of queries?

Comment: you should use a `trie` guava have some implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best collection type for this problem is `SortedSet`.  You would need two of them in fact:

1. Words in regular order.
2. Words with their characters inverted.

Once these `SortedSet`s have been created, you can use method `subSet` to find what you are looking for.  For example:

1. Words starting with `"Foo"`:

   ```
    forwardSortedSet.subSet("Foo","Fop");
   ```
2. Words ending with `"Bar"`:

   ```
    backwardSortedSet.subSet("raB","raC");
   ```

The reason we are "adding" 1 to the last search character is to obtain the whole range.  The "ending" word is excluded from the `subSet`, so there is no problem.

**EDIT:**  Of the two concrete classes that implement `SortedSet` in the standard Java library, use `TreeSet`.  The other (`ConcurrentSkipListSet`) is oriented to concurrent programs and thus not optimized for this situation.

Comment: Why a set instead of a sorted list?

Comment: Where do you need the inverted set for? For the searching for Strings that end on certain chars?

Comment: @Kon: because it doesn't exist. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-there-is-no-sortedlist-in-java

Comment: Yes, presumably. You could reverse your search term then search the backwards set for the starting characters. Ie, to search for "Bar" at the end of a string, you reverse all the strings, then search for "raB" to start. This allows you to continue using a binary search and keeping your search times down to log n complexity

Comment: @Amadan One can trivially sort a List, and the OP never specified regarding uniqueness being allowed.

Comment: Nice, what would be the best implementation to use (since `SortedSet` is an interface)? `TreeSet`?

Comment: @Kon: You can. However, `SortedSet` is kept sorted by a tree structure in the background, which allows you to use `subSet("Foo", "Fop")` to get everything that starts with `"Foo"` very quickly. A `List` has no such structure, even if you sort it, so you'd have to iterate through it to find the elements. The former is, I presume, O(log n); the latter is O(n). (More correctly, O(log n) is the complexity if you're working on a `TreeSet`; a `SortedSet` could be anything :p )

Comment: @Kon  I don't know your reasons for not including that as an answer.  I definitely think it **is** a valid one, and we need to make the OP aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while but I needed to implement this now and did some testing.

I already have a `HashSet<String>` as source so generation of all other datastructures is included in search time. 100 different sources are used and each time the data structures need to be regenerated. I only need to match a few single Strings each time. These tests ran on Android.

Methods:

1. Simple loop through `HashSet` and call `endsWith()` on
   each string
2. Simple loop through `HashSet` and perform precompiled
       `Pattern` match (regex) on each string.
3. Convert `HashSet` to single `String` joined by `\n` and
       single match on whole String.
4. Generate `SortedTree` with reversed `Strings` from
   `HashSet`. Then match with `subset()` as explained by @Mario Rossi.

Results:

```
Duration for method 1: 173ms (data setup:0ms search:173ms)
Duration for method 2: 6909ms (data setup:0ms search:6909ms)
Duration for method 3: 3026ms (data setup:2377ms search:649ms)
Duration for method 4: 2111ms (data setup:2101ms search:10ms)
```

Conclusion:

`SortedSet`/`SortedTree` is extremely fast in searching. Much faster than just looping through all `Strings`. However, creating the structure takes a lot of time. Regexes are much slower, but generating a single large `String` out of hundreds of `Strings` is more of a bottleneck on Android/Java.

If only a few matches need to be made, then you better loop through your collection. If you have much more matches to make it may be very useful to use a `SortedTree`!

Answer (score 2):

If the list of words is stable (not many words are added or deleted), a very good second alternative is to create 2 lists:

1. One with the words in normal order.
2. The second with the characters in each word reversed.

For speed purposes, make them `ArrayList`s.  Never `LinkedList`s or other variants which perform extremely bad on random access (the core of binary search; see below).

After the lists are created, they can be sorted with method `Collections.sort` (only once each) and then searched with `Collections.binarySearch`.  For example:

```
    Collections.sort(forwardList);
    Collections.sort(backwardList);
```

And then to search for words starting in "Foo":

```
    int i= Collections.binarySearch(forwardList,"Foo") ;
    while( i < forwardList.size() && forwardList.get(i).startsWith("Foo") ) {
        // Process String forwardList.get(i)
        i++;
    }
```

And words ending in "Bar":

```
    int i= Collections.binarySearch(backwardList,"raB") ;
    while( i < backwardList.size() &&  backwardList.get(i).startsWith("raB") ) {
        // Process String backwardList.get(i)
        i++;
    }
```