# Java Comparator in Sets with equal items

Tags: java, set, equality, comparator, treeset

Normally in a TreeSet there shouldn't be two equal items. But in reality there are often situations where you want to maintain kind of a sorted List instead of a Set. Still there is afaik no TreeList or any SortedList in Java. Though you can of course use Collections.sort().

My question is: **what is the proper way to use a TreeSet (or any sorted set) so that it is also capable of containing equal items?**

I normally do something like that:

```
new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        int result = Float.compare(o1.getDistance(), o2.getDistance());
        
        //both distances are equal so we use the object hash as distinctive
        //property.
        if (result == 0) {
            result = Integer.compare(System.identityHashCode(o1), 
                System.identityHashCode(o2))
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

While this works very well, this has of course the disadvantage that there is still the slim chance of a **hash collision**, that would lead to **missing objects** in the TreeSet.

So I wonder if there is any better way to really distinguish these objects properly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-there-is-no-sortedlist-in-java

Comment: Oh, and don't use a TreeSet that way, unless your purpose to confuse other people.

Comment: You can add a field to MyObject which should always be unique for different records. Or you can use a List and sort that.

Comment: Sometimes the only difference between two object is, that they are two different objects. So of course, if I can add an unique ID i'd use that for sure. But sometimes that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using

```
import com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset;
```

effortless and successfully.

You shouldn't try to use workarounds when good libraries are around.

There may be other libs as well, of course.

**Later**

I should have raised a red flag at "equal" in combination with "set". This is a no-no. You can have equal multiple equal keys in a Map.

If you want to store objects repeatedly, even if they are equal, use a List; it's up to you to decide whether an equal element should be added or not.

Another thought:

Maybe you want an IdentityHashMap which uses reference equality rather than equals.

BUT be prepared for endless difficulties if you violate the hashCode/equals contract in your class.

Comment: I just tested TreeMultiset and it has the same problem. The only difference is that it keeps two identical objects instead of one. But if I want to have two objects that are equal according to the Comparator but still have different properties, then I lose one of these objects. E.g. if I add two objects A(1) with id 1 and A(2) with id 2 and both are equal according to the Comparator<A> then the Multiset only contains two times A(1) but A(2) disappeared.

Comment: equal is equal is equal. Maybe I should point out... see updated answer,

Comment: Hmm ... I guess I discovered a very special case where I need multiple values in a sorted collection, that might be equal according to the Comparator but not to hashCode/equals.

I think the best way to solve this is to either
1) use the TreeSet and prevent a possible hash collision
OR 
2) write a red-black tree based List implementation. Still for most of the times your answer will be doing the job, so I accept it as the solution :)

Answer (score -1):

```
package newfeature;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;`enter code here`
class employee {
    String name;
    int idno;
    public employee(int idno, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.idno = idno;
    }
}
public class setcom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<employee> emset = new HashSet<>();
        emset.add(new employee(1, "rohan"));
        emset.add(new employee(2, "sohan"));
        emset.add(new employee(3, "mohan"));
        emset.add(new employee(4, "zohan"));
        for (employee em : emset) {
            System.out.println(em.name);
        }
        Set<employee> sorted = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<employee>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(employee o1, employee o2) {
                return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
            }
        });
        sorted.addAll(emset);
        System.out.println("*******separotor*******");
        for (employee em : sorted) {
            System.out.println(em.name);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? It just shows that you can sort items in a tree set, but that was never in question.