# Replace single element in list with two or more other elements without disturbing the order of the remaining elements

Tags: java, list

Is there a way to replace a single element in a list with TWO or more other elements without disturbing the rest of the list ? I understand you can replace one element with another, but i'm looking for more than one element to be added. The use case is that I would like to split a given element into two or more elements based on a particular condition.

For example: Let's say the list contains the path from node A to node F on a Graph as follows: 
`A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F` 
 I would like to replace node C with two other elements say node X and node Y. The final list should look as follows:

`A -> B -> X -> Y -> D -> E -> F`

Note: I am still thinking through the implementation and I have not finalized on using any particular type of list (ArrayList, LinkedList etc.) yet.

Comment: What do you mean by _"without disturbing the rest of the list"_?

Comment: Yes you can insert elements but that will move all elements after the inserted element back one...

Comment: What list implementation is this? (It makes a huge difference.) For something like ArrayList, you'd just replace one and insert another one before or after it.

Comment: if the list is sorted, i would like to maintain the sorted order.

Comment: When you replace the element with element(s) will they be in the correct spot or will the list need to be re-sorted?

Comment: Maybe you want a sorted set check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-there-is-no-sortedlist-in-java

Comment: @brso05 The new elements will maintain the sorted order

Comment: @JonSkeet Let's assume we're using an ArrayList for now. Does the solution change if i'm using any other implementation (say, a LinkedList etc.) ?

Comment: @Shetty: Well for one thing, insertion into a linked list doesn't require copying. (Although IIRC, the Java API doesn't make it easy to do this as efficiently as we might like.) And if it's a sorted list, insertion at a point makes no sense. For another, an array-backed list (Arrays.asList) wouldn't allow insertion at all.

Comment: @Shetty If you are using ArrayList look at Bogdan Balas answer...

Comment: @ZouZou, JonSkeet, brso05: I've added an example to the question. Please take a look and see if that helps clarify my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add to a Java list by using myList.add({index}, {object});
So if you want to split something at index 3 for example you could do:

```
myList.set(3, newObject1);
myList.add(3, newObject2);
```

So now everything gets shifted to the left and newObject1 will be at index 4.  Be careful about doing this in an for loop though, things can get messy.

Comment: The upper case `Set` and `Add` make me wonder if you noticed the `java` tag.

Comment: Woops, too much C# recently but the principal is the same.