# Is there a sorted object list in java?

Tags: java

I have an object with the following memebers:

```
class XNode {
    // key
    long magicNumber;   

    // metadata:
    int x;
    iny y;
    int z;
    double angle;
    double tempreture;
}
```

I want to use order list (the key is magicNumber).

Is there a list in java which already implements the add/remove/update in a order manner ? (I dont want to use Collections.sort for every operation).

Comment: ArrayList or LinkedList if duplication is allowed ?

Comment: Short answer, not really, long answer, `TreeSet` "might" help and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java) might shed some more light on it

Comment: Do you need to allow duplicates?

Comment: no duplicates are allowed

Comment: If you do not need support for duplicates, then `TreeSet` will allow you to iterate in sorted order. However, it doesn't support random access (e.g., the `i`-th element). So whether it will work for you depends on your requirements. You might also take a look at the new [`SortedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) of Java FX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> no duplicates are allowed

First, in `XNode` there is a typo. I believe

```
iny y;
```

should be

```
int y;
```

Then you might use a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (for example [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)),

```
Comparator<XNode> comp = new Comparator<XNode>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(XNode o1, XNode o2) {
        return Long.valueOf(o1.magicNumber).compareTo(o2.magicNumber);
    }
};
SortedSet<XNode> set = new TreeSet<>(comp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and compare by your `magicNumber`:

```
public int compare(XNode other) {
    return Long.compare(this.magicNumber, other.magicNumber);
}
```

and use a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Answer (score 2):

There's no sorted list, but you can use a sorted set with a `Comparator`:

```
Set<XNode> set = new TreeSet<>((a, b) -> Long.compare(a.magicNumber, b.magicNumber));
```

This comparator (lambda) distinguishes sorts on magicNumber.