# Adding integers from a file into a existing array while sorting?

Tags: java, arrays, file

Basically I need to read numbers from a file into a existing array, but while doing this I need to also sort the numbers being added into their appropriate numerical position in descending order. While also checking to see if any of the number being loaded exist and if they do excluding them from the load. If there is anything that I need to provide please let me know.

Comment: The array contains only numbers which occur only once in your file in descending order?

Comment: You need to provide us with some effort and a specific problem. Please see how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check out the accepted answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java

Comment: yes the array only contains numbers which can only occur once in the array. The file contains some duplicates of the existing array's numbers and some new numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tree set. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

If you have to use an array, try using binary search to find the element or the position the element should be at (the `while` loop commonly used exits in both cases, providing you one index in the array). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int).

Unfortunately, that's about all the detail I can provide. Please provide more details to get more details. Code snippets are welcome here but don't put too much.