# Java sorted collection with a count-based sublist

Tags: java, collections

We know we can use

```
Collections.sort
```

to sort a list after all elements inserted.

But if elements are inserted once a time, maybe the `SortedMap` is more effective?

Though, the `SortedMap` lack the `subList` method.

What I need is something like `SortedMap` can effectively insert small amount of elements many times, and can always get a 1~1000 sublist top-down with a `Comparator` interface.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java) could help you probably.

Comment: @zencv the question doesn't mention the `subList`, that exactly what i need

Comment: Doesn't `NavigableSet` support those kind of subviews? I think methods like `NavigableSet.subSet(start,end)` could probably work here.

Answer (score 1):

I think a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) is a [`NavigableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) which in turn has methods like [`subSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet-E-E-), `tailSet`, [`headSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#headSet-E-), [`ceiling`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#ceiling-E-) and `floor` for this kind of problems.

So you could do something like:

```
SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
SortedSet<Integer> subset = set.subSet(3,7);
System.out.println(subset); //[3,4,5,6]
```

Obviously you can create you [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) with whatever [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) you want, and perform the searches in the order that you find more convenient.

```
Comparator<Integer> reverse = Collections.reverseOrder();
SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(reverse);
//same thing here
```

Comment: This is a WRONG answer. All subset/tail/head... and Comparator are VALUE-BASED, not COUNT-BASED.

Comment: @rufushuang A much better comment would have been: "Edwin, since comparators are value-based, as are all the methods you suggested, how do you think I could get a constant range of elements out of the set then"?. You can see that my style of comment would have encouraged me to come back and try to improve or correct my answer. You can catch more flies with honey than you do with vinegar.