# Multiset in Android

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I have a structure

```
class A
{
    float key;
    Foo data;
}
```

I need to maintain an array of these structures sorted by `key`. Insertion and deletion of elements into the array must be efficient (say `O(log n)`). `key` is not guaranteed to be unique. Also I need to enumerate the array in the sorted order. Random access by index is not needed.

If I were using C++, I would use `std::multiset` here.

What would you suggest to use for Java for Android?

Comment: Do you require your key to be `float` or would `Float` work? There is overhead for boxing primitives into objects but if your set of data doesn't change at high rate you could use a `TreeMap<Float, A>`.

Comment: `TreeMap` only works with unique keys, doesn't it? In my situation key is not unique. So two or more elements may have the same key value.

Comment: Arf, yes. You could potentially work around that with a  `TreeSet<A>` with a comparator that includes the `Foo` object in the comparison in case `key`s are identical. Requires that foo is somehow comparable and not duplicate. Or `TreeMap<Float, List<A>>` for true multi mapping (or guava's implementation https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained). Otherwise a sorted list / tree structure of `A`s but there is no standard collection for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Guava Multiset](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) in order to achieve what you want.
In Android Studio you just need to add the following dependancy to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
```

Then you just need to declare a `Multiset` of your class, like this:

```
Multiset<A> multiset = HashMultiset.create();

multiset.add(new A(1.5, "a"));
```

If you take a look at the docs the available methods should allow you to do what you need.

Comment: When I enumerate `Multiset`, does it yield entries in the sorted order?

Comment: There is also an implementation of [SortedMultiset](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SortedMultiset.html) , from the docs: `A Multiset which maintains the ordering of its elements, according to either their natural order or an explicit Comparator.`

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the `PriorityQueue` class. Pushing items to a priority queue is `O(logn)` and deleting is `O(logn)`. As well, you can have duplicates unlike `TreeSet`. You cannot go through index by index, but you can go through the queue sequentially. Lastly, order is of course sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use `Comparable` interface and `TreeSet` to solve your issue as bellow

Create your Data Structure class as bellow

```
public class YourDataSructure implements Comparable<YourDataSructure> {

    public float key;
    public String data;

    public YourDataSructure(float key,String data) {
        this.key = key;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(YourDataSructure o) {
        if(key > o.key)
        {
            return 1;
        }else if(key <= o.key)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

And use this code to add the data

```
TreeSet<YourDataSructure> treeset = new TreeSet<>();

        treeset.add(new YourDataSructure(34,"test 1"));
        treeset.add(new YourDataSructure(22.11f,"test 2"));
        treeset.add(new YourDataSructure(34.12f,"test 3"));
        treeset.add(new YourDataSructure(11.12f,"test 4"));
        treeset.add(new YourDataSructure(11.1f,"test 5"));
        treeset.add(new YourDataSructure(66.32f,"test 6"));
        treeset.add(new YourDataSructure(69.55f,"test 7"));
        treeset.add(new YourDataSructure(34.43f,"test 8"));
        treeset.add(new YourDataSructure(11f,"test 9"));
        treeset.add(new YourDataSructure(11f,"test 10"));

        treeset.forEach(new Consumer<YourDataSructure>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(YourDataSructure t) {
                System.out.println(t.key + " " + t.data);
            }
        });
```

Works fine for me

Here is the output sorted w.r.t. key value and duplicate keys also allowed.

```
11.0 test 10
11.0 test 9
11.1 test 5
11.12 test 4
22.11 test 2
34.0 test 1
34.12 test 3
34.43 test 8
66.32 test 6
69.55 test 7
```

Comment: In your example `test 10` will overwrite `test 9`, won't it? Because their key is `11f`, and duplicated keys are not allowed in `TreeSet`.

Comment: I have added output of the code here duplicate keys are allowed as you can see. This is happening due to overriding of compareTo()