# Using synchronizedList with for loop and adding items inside it

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I'm using

```
Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<T>())
```

part of the code is:

```
list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<T>());

public void add(T arg) {
    int i;
    synchronized (list) {
        for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            T arg2 = list.get(i);

            if (arg2.compareTo(arg) < 0) {
                list.add(i, arg);
                break;
            }

        }
```

Is it right that for loop is actually using **iterator** and therefore I *must* wrap the for with **synchronized**?

Is it thread-safe to use synchronized and make addition inside it like I did here?

I'm sorry if these questions are very basic, I'm new to the subject and didn't find answers on the internet.
Thank you!!

Comment: Yes, you must synchronize the loop as you did. Make additions inside the loop is thread-safe but your list should be immutable during the loop

Comment: You may also be interested in reading [Why is there no SortedList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java).

Comment: Also: you will never add the first element to the list with this logic, so the list will remain forever empty :)

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you, I corrected my mistake. I need to save the maximum value of the list. I think that I need to update the maximum value inside the sychronized block as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it right that for loop is actually using iterator and therefore I must wrap the for with synchronized?

There are two parts to your question.

Firstly, no, you're not using an iterator here, this is a basic for loop.

The enhanced for loop is the for loop which uses an iterator:

```
for (T element : list) { ... }
```

You can see [in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) how this uses the iterator - search for where it says "The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form".

Secondly, even though you're not using an iterator, you *do* need `synchronized`. The two are orthogonal.

You are doing multiple operations (the `size`, the `get` and the `add`), with dependencies between them. You need to make sure that no other thread interferes with your logic:

- the `get` depends on the `size`, since you don't want to try to get an element with `index >= size`, for instance;
- the `add` depends on the `get`, since you're apparently trying to ensure the list elements are ordered. If another thread could sneak in and change the element after you `get` it, you might insert the new element in the wrong place.

You correctly avoid this potential interference this through synchronization over `list`, *and* creating the `synchronizedList` in such a way that nothing other than the `synchronizedList` can get direct access to the underlying list.

Answer (score 1):

If your arg2.compareTo(arg) never return 0 (zero) you can use TreeSet. Will be much more simple:

```
set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new TreeSet<T>());

public void add(T arg) {
    set.add(arg);
}
```

If you need hold same items (compareTo returns 0) then use the list:

```
list = new ArrayList<T>();

public void add(T arg) {
    synchronized (list) {
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, arg);
        list.add(index, arg);
    }
}
```

First and second cases complexity will be log(N) (10 for 1000 items). Your code complexity is N (1000 for 1000 items).

Comment: You could just use `Collections.binarySearch` to find the element in the list, and then you wouldn't need the restriction of `arg2.compareTo(arg) != 0`.

Comment: Thank you. Update second case with binarySearch