# Java: What is the best way to traverse and insert element into a ranked linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

Due to the frequent insertions and deletions at the head and tail of the linked list, I have chosen to use the linked list from the Java API. And the linked list will be ranked in descending order, i.e. `100,98,97,95,90`

`LinkedList<MyObject> mylinkedlist = new LinkedList<MyObject>();`

```
Myobject new_value = new MyObject(96);
```

Occasionally I have to insert elements into this linked list(not at the head and tail). Because the linked list must be in descending order, I have to traverse the linked list in **descending order** from the head or **ascending order from the tail** and then insert it into a correct index.

I came up with an attempt as follow

```
  int i;
  for(int i=0; i<mylinkedlist.size(); i++)
  {
      if(mylinkedlist.get(num).getInt() <= new_value.getInt()){
         break;
      }
  }

   mylinkedlist.add(i,new_value)
```

I can just tell my code above is really poor. However, is there a way to optimize my code and avoid using `break` and at the same time , also avoid traversing the entire linked list because it could be super long ?

It would be greatly appreciated if code example could be provided. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Sincere apologies for not phrasing my questions properly. MY problem should be that given the linked list currently contains `100,98,97,95,90`, if I want to insert a new and different value, say `96`. How should one detect the index of the linked list such that the new value `96` can be inserted into it, **while preserving the descending order of the linked list?**

It is really important that the (1) descending order of the list and the (2) uniqueness of elements in the list are preserved in this problem.

Comment: using an iterator.

Comment: Note that accessing a linked list's elements by index is not fast at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using another data structure, as [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

This class implements SortedSet and use natural ordering or a comparator provided at the creation time. Then you'll just have to add the object, it will be automatically sorted.

### Using natural ordering

In MyObject class:

```
public int compareTo(MyObject o) {
    return this.getInt() - o.getInt()
}
```

Using TreeSet:

```
SortedSet<MyObject> objectSet = new TreeSet<MyObject>();
Myobject newObject = new MyObject(95);
objectSet.add(newObject);
```

### Using Comparator

If you don't want to modify `MyObject` class (for instance):

```
class MyObjectComp implements Comparator<MyObject> {

    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        return o1.getInt() - o2.getInt();
    }

}

SortedSet<MyObject> objectSet = new TreeSet<MyObject>(new MyObjectComp());
Myobject newObject = new MyObject(95);
objectSet.add(newObject);
```

### Descending Set

For a descending set, it is possible to use TreeSet's descendingSet method:

```
SortedSet<MyObject> objectSet = new TreeSet<MyObject>(new MyObjectComp()).descendingSet();
Myobject newObject = new MyObject(95);
objectSet.add(newObject);
```

For more information about sorted structures in Java, you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java).

Comment: How come it doesn’t say it is automatically sorted in the link ? And in my case, I need a list that is in descending order and another list in ascending order . Would it be able to do that ? Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant TreeSet instead of TreeList. I've editted the answer.
The TreeSet's method descendingSet should provide you a descending Set

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use a list, there is a possibility to achieve the same result using the standard API: [`Collections.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-) method provides exactly the feature you are looking for.

So the code would resemble the following:

```
private static void insert(List<MyObject> items, MyObject newValue) {
  int insertionPoint =
      Collections.binarySearch(items, 
                               newValue, 
                               // reversed comparator is used because the items are in DESC order
                               Comparator.comparingInt(MyObject::getInt).reversed());
  // if newValue is not in the list, insertionPoint will be negative, see javadoc
  int i = (insertionPoint < 0) ? -insertionPoint - 1 : insertionPoint;
  // add it at i, even if duplicate (?)
  items.add(i, newValue);
}
```

This *does not* really optimise the solution, just cleans it up a bit, eliminating the *break* and reusing the standard API. The javadoc gives some detail about its efficiency:

> This method runs in log(n) time for a "random access" list (which provides near-constant-time positional access). If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons.

If the list becomes huge and you begin to look for efficiency, I'd recommend to switch to `ArrayList`, which implements `RandomAccess` and will be more efficient provided that the order of items is respected.

If your collection does not allow duplicates, it will be much better to use a sorted set.