# Re-arrange ArrayList elements

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have `n` number of list of items, containing name and position. If I delete a row from list, I want to re-arrange the positions of the list.

For example:

```
Vijay  01
Dhas   02
Arun   03
prabhu 04
```

If I delete Dhas from the list, Arun's position should be `02` and prabhu's position should be `03`.

My model class is

```
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private int position;

    public Model(String name, int position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

}
```

I tried the following:

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.imvDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    int tempPreviousValue;
                    for(int i = position ; i < mData.size()-1 ; i++){
                        int deletedPosition = mData.get(i).getPosition();
                        tempPreviousValue = mData.get(position+1).getPosition();
                        mData.get(position+1).setPosition(deletedPosition);
                    }
                    mData.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            }); 
        }
```

But I am not getting the correct order. Can anyone give some ideas to re-arrange the array?

Comment: Just remove it in activity/fragment/anywhere you fill that list, not in adapter, and there call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: after you delete item from the list, you can just set the `item.setPosition(list.indexOf(item))` to the position of the item in the list

Comment: If you delete item from List it will automatically update the positions and you don't need to do anything. What exactly you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MaksimNovikov List position will be changed. But in my model position I need to change.

Comment: @VijayDhas what is the purpose of position in the model?

Comment: @VijayDhas you can use sortedList, for more info check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java

Comment: I am having position in model. I will get it from server. For example seat arrangement I am having 10 seats. 1st seat allocated to Vijay, 2nd seat allocated to Dhas, like wise 10 seats allocated. If I delete 5th seat person 6th seat person should allocated to seat 5 and need to change up to 10 seats.

Comment: @HamidReza.. I no need to sort the list. I want to swap the value of position in model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
int positionToDelete = 2;
Model modelToDelete = modelList.get(positionToDelete - 1);
modelList.remove(modelToDelete);
for(int i = positionToDelete - 1; i < modelList.size(); i++){
  Model modelToChange = modelList.get(i);
  modelToChange.setPosition(modelToChange.getPosition() - 1);
}
```

The list will be this before deleting:

```
[{name = Vijay, position = 1},
 {name = Dhas, position = 2},
 {name = Arun, position = 3},
 {name = prabhu, position = 4}]
```

And this after deleting:

```
[{name = Vijay, position = 1},
 {name = Arun, position = 2},
 {name = prabhu, position = 3}]
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##hVNNT8MwDL3zK6yeWnVU4uPEADHgyJc0xAVxCCxsGW0yJW7RmPbbh9OmJVkHnNb52c/2y/OcVWx/PvnYbN5yZgzcMiFXewAGGYo3cEE14bmNAiy0qBhyGKMWcgqSFXwYAEIiLJQRKJQc7jVQ@ZoTV80Se4WDIDlpGgDgTJjM4nDm8bt4m03YTxeLroNersuU4x0xxB235lhq6dGGZZUSEzCuyJv0n9lCErsUNX5w4/Wa/zV3O0BX/LtC/ylxcV9xrcWE79AFVfPRmy1aueWi1H6k0QC8PlHa/kmjddR2cx2dY@ZkqKxEkWc3wuBp/ejnUNgfG7C68U8va6Q1W1ok3oqZjJk6XrexRY2BoicxZ0sa7CAZbEPXM2YIOewjI11KQo76yEKz11lJ2HFCUJLUpnVyuZ3qVynoMpwnnl@AOeXGS4O8yFSJGV2AxFzG0SV/V5oDsXOk7BPSrds/cTfhv@ujurapVvbDRtR6tEY0D@xIMrJX3KveJ0Wa8p9EzQtV8Thgckk0Y@0u4RnI5xoScupRGfFFh0TRNO1cE8x5NWNy2p9TJO0BB3mZ7/IQCY7HW8sZe5fko3fk@lfFbel6s/kG)

Or if you already know the Model you want to delete, the first two lines are this instead:

```
Model modelToDelete = ...; // Model retrieved from some place
int positionToDelete = modelToDelete.getPosition();
```

The rest stays the same.

Comment: Thanks Kavin. Works good. Temporally I fixed this as solution. But If i receive input like this new Model("Item 1",12),
new Model("Item 2",10),
new Model("Item 3",12),
new Model("Item 4",44),
new Model("Item 5",35),
new Model("Item 6",99),
new Model("Item 7",54)), we will be in trouble. Is there any way to solve this?  For this only I try to swap the values. Please let me know.

Comment: @VijayDhas About that example you give. When we remove the model `Item 4` (position `44`), what will it become? Will it becomes `[{Item 1, 12}, {Item 2, 10}, {Item 3, 12}, {Item 5, 44}, {Item 6, 35}, {item 7, 99}]`, or will the items first be sorted on position, so it will becomes `[{Item 2, 10}, {Item 1, 12}, {Item 3, 12}, {Item 5, 35}, {Item 7, 44}, {Item 6, 54}]` when deleting position `44`?

Comment: @VijayDhas ? What do you mean last value also removed? I was asking what the Model-list should become when you remove the `{"Item 4",44}`-Model.

Comment: Older list:

`{Item 1",12},
{Item 2",10},
{Item 3",12},
{Item 4",44},
{Item 5",35},
{Item 6",99},
{Item 7",54}`


After remove itme 2

`{Item 1",12},

{Item 3",10},

{Item 4",12},

{Item 5",44},

{Item 6",35},

{Item 7",99}`

Item 2 value 10 is swap to item 3, Item 3 value 12 is swap to item 4. like wise all the value will be swaped to end. So last value will be removed. In this example 54 is removed. That’s why I mentioned last position will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I actually recommend just using a plain list of names, and then relying on `List#indexOf` to find the positions.

```
String[] names = new String[] { "Vijay", "Dhas", "Arun", "prabhu" };
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(names);
list.remove("Dhas");
System.out.println(list.indexOf("Arun"));  // should be 1, was 2 before deletion
```

You may also use `List<Model>`, and the same logic applies.  I am advocating that you let the list API maintain the position number for you, which it already does.

Comment: I can not use plain list. I am having Model class. I need to do change in model class.

Comment: Doesn't change my answer.  You may replace `String` with `Model` in my answer.  The list API already does the work of maintaining positions, and you should use it.

Comment: I am having position in model. I will get it from server. For example seat arrangement I am having 10 seats. 1st seat allocated to Vijay, 2nd seat allocated to Dhas, like wise 10 seats allocated. If I delete 5th seat person 6th seat person should allocated to seat 5 and need to change up to 10 seats. So I want to change in Model. Not in List.

Comment: ...but to change model, you must change your data source, which is your list.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an loop, and use increment index as new position like this

```
    mData.remove(position);
    for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
        mData.get(i).setPosition(i);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or if your position in model starts from numer 1, use `.setPosition(i+1)`.

One thing, don't use position in recyclerview adapter, because this may have a wrong number, use `holder.getAdapterPosition();` instead.

Comment: I am having position in model. I will get it from server. For example seat arrangement I am having 10 seats. 1st seat allocated to Vijay, 2nd seat allocated to Dhas, like wise 10 seats allocated. If I delete 5th seat person 6th seat person should allocated to seat 5 and need to change up to 10 seats.

Comment: Above code will do this, but do it outside an adapter, let change main source, not source in adapter. For clarity, you should remove one of position on a main data source too, not just in adapter.

Comment: i will be the mdata postion. I want to update the mdata.setPostion with previous value. Simply said want to swap the values in sequence .

Comment: @grabarz121 Why you add model after removing ?

Comment: And I think you really don't know, what you'll want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to refresh Adapter with `notifyDataSetChanged();`
and write code like that :-

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            mData.get(position).setPosition(position);
        }
```

also add one more method for remove item in adapter.

```
public void remove_item(int position) {
       mData.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.imvDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    for (int i=mData.size()-1;i>position;i--){
                        mData.get(i).setPosition(mData.get(i-1).getPosition());
                    }
                    mData.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method something like this

```
public void removeItem(int position){
    // just a safe check
    if(position >= getItemCount() ){
        return;
    }

    mData.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

then call and pass the position  you wanted to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using `Java8` streams:

```
List<String> l2 = list.stream().filter(a -> !a.equals("Dhas")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this would create a new list.