# C# has no SortedList<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to solve a problem in which it would be useful to have a data structure like

```
var list = new SortedList<int>(); 
list.Add(3); // list = { 3 } 
list.Add(1); // list = { 1, 3 }
list.Add(2); // list = { 1, 2, 3 }
int median = list[list.Length / 2];
```

i.e.

- O(n) insertion
- O(1) lookup by index

but I can't see that such a thing exists? I see that there's some confusing `SortedList<T,U>` and then an interface `SortedList`, but neither of those are what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_sortedlist.htm ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663613/why-is-there-no-sortedlistt-in-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there no SortedList<T> in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663613/why-is-there-no-sortedlistt-in-net)

Comment: @PetSerAl Sorry, I meant O(n) insertion. My bad.

Comment: You could always try to [make one yourself](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/CSHARP/9_Custom_Collection_in_C__-_Part_1.aspx).

Comment: The main problem with a pure SortedList<T> is with mutable items. With the current SortedList you should use an immutable for the key values

Answer (score 0):

The sorted list in the .NET framework is an associative list (that is it is for key/value pairs). You can use a regular `List<T>` if you use its binary search functionality, which works if you keep the list sorted at all times. You can encapsulate it in an extension method:

```
static class SortedListExtensions {
    public static void SortedAdd<T>(this List<T> list, T value) {
        int insertIndex = list.BinarySearch(value);
        if (value < 0) {
            value = ~value;
        }
        list.Insert(insertIndex, value);
    }

    //Added bonus: a faster Contains method
    public static bool SortedContains<T>(this List<T> list, T value) {
        return list.BinarySearch(value) >= 0;
    }
}


List<int> values = new List<int>();
values.SortedAdd(3);
values.SortedAdd(1);
values.SortedAdd(2);
```